# Dynamically created File type validation

Tags: jquery, html, file-type

This code contains jQuery for adding and removing input type file dynamically on button click, I wanted to add validation on the onChange event button it is not working:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 1;

    $j("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $j(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
 //<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>'
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="file" name="ImageFile'+counter+'" id="ImageFile'+counter+'" value="" accept="audio/*,video/*,image/*"  multiple="multiple" required/>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    alert('<input type="file" name="ImageFile'+counter+'" id="ImageFile'+counter+'" value="" accept="audio/*,video/*,image/*"  multiple="multiple" required/>');
    counter++;
    alert($j("#ImageFile").val());
     });

     $j("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $j("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });
     $j("#upload_type").on('change',function (){
    alert(); });

 $j("#ImageFile"+counter-1).on('change', function (){
     alert($j("#ImageFile").val());
     var avatar = $j("#ImageFile").val();
     var extension = avatar.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
     alert(avatar);
     if(avatar.length < 1) {
             avatarok = 0;

         }
         else if (extension!="PNG" && extension!="JPG" && extension!="GIF" && extension!="JPEG"){ 
             avatarok = 0;
             alert("invalid extension "+extension);
         }
         else {
             alert("valid");
             avatarok = 1;
         }
         if(avatarok == 1) {
             $('.formValidation').addClass("sending");
             $("#form").submit();
         }
         else {
             $('.formValidation').addClass("validationError");
         }
         return false;
     });
         $j("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $j('#ImageFile' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
     }) ;
  });
```

The change event is not triggered, but when I manually add a input type file the change event is triggered. Why is this?

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>

</div></CENTER></td></tr>
<tr><td >
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'></td><td>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'></td><td>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'></td></tr></table>
```

This is the Html markup.

Comment: since your element is dynamicaly added to the DOM use

 $j("body").on('change', "#upload_type" ,function (){
    alert(); });

 $j("body").on('change', "#ImageFile"+counter-1, function (){

to listen these element

Comment: That worked, but can u explain y did this happen?

Comment: yeah, when you do this $j("#upload_type").on('change',function (){
    alert(); }) it attach an event at the element find when the script is first executed, with $j("body").on('change', "#upload_type" ,function (){ alert(); }), the listener is attach to the body, and it's triggered only when the the element an element that match the second argument send the good event, by it use more ressource for the client computer

Comment: i have one more query,  my file type accepts multiple file bt validation is done only for the first file, how do i get the array of file, it would b nice if u add snippet .

Comment: Got the solution for multiple file, but i have a major problem, the extension which are hard codded i hav to retrive through database through jsp, and m new in jsp!